# Sweet potato variety identification

Tags: identification, sweet-potato

That's how they look like just after harvesting. Flesh is light yellow, after cut fresh tuber in half, milky juice appears (it's also visible on damaged roots on pic below).

[image: Sweet potato]

[image: Sweet potato]

Slips before moving outdoors:
[image: Sweet potato]

Tuber grows:

[image: Sweet potato]

Vines are not able to climb. The plant creates much more vines than Beauregard for example and leaves are much larger. Also, they are mature very quickly, I think 2.5-3 months is enough if summer is hot, but I got pretty good size tubers even after 2 months (but most of them were small)

Comment: +1 Fun question. Are You sure those are sweet potatoes instead of some other tuber? The leaves look a lot different than any potato I've seen. Do they taste like 'sweet potatoes'?

Comment: I assume you know that sweet potato is not potato + sweet taste, that's completly different plant. Yes, those are sweet potato. Haven't you really seen leaves like that? Various species have similar leaves (all purple or stokes purple for example, look  here: https://youtu.be/yulzgQswS80). Of course, taste is not the same as orange sweet potato, various species has various taste

Comment: Sorry, have actually eaten the tubers only once; never seen the plant. Thanks for the info(and good luck with the Q)!